# Struct with local references vs Class with local references? Swift performance

Tags: ios, swift, performance, memory

As far as I know if a struct contains more than one reference as property stored, it's (2*reference) more expensive to allocate it than a class.
Is it the same case in local variables?

```
struct ViewNavigationRouter {

    private let firstViewController : UIViewController

    init(firstViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.firstViewController = firstViewController
    }

    func navigate(from: UIViewController) {

        let viewController1 : UIViewController = xxx
        let viewController2 : UIViewController = xxx
        let viewController3 : UIViewController = xxx
    }
}



class ViewNavigationRouter {

    private let firstViewController : UIViewController

    init(firstViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.firstViewController = firstViewController
    }

    func navigate(from: UIViewController) {

        let viewController1 : UIViewController = xxx
        let viewController2 : UIViewController = xxx
        let viewController3 : UIViewController = xxx
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "more expensive to allocate"? Memory-wise? Do you have a link to where you got to know about this?

Comment: Yes, you can watch this video about it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/
If the struct has references, each of them is allocated in the heap and it’s adding 2 extra words (type and reference counting), even the struct is allocated in the stack

Comment: It seems that the section that the question refers to is around 15 minutes in, where they point out that to copy a struct with N references inside, all these references have to be get their retain count increased (whereas if you add another reference to a class with N references inside, none of this has to happen).

Comment: "If the struct has references, each of them is allocated in the heap and it’s adding 2 extra words (type and reference counting), even the struct is allocated in the stack". Well, the same thing happens when you allocate a new class instance. This is not really an effect of allocating the struct, but of allocating the objects that the references point to. Also, if you copy a struct, the second struct will have its references pointed to the same objects on the heap, so there is no duplication there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it is the same in this case as all the members in struct ViewNavigationRouter and in class ViewNavigationRouter are - instances of classes (firstViewController : UIViewController). I do not see more wide context of this, but it looks like this here.

I suggest you to read this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html
many times, specially focusing to parts Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types and Classes Are Reference Types.

The most important difference is related to that what happends when you copy the content identifier is "pointing to". I suggest you further reading:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.htm
and to tak a look to examples. Than you will see that difference is not about memory performance, but on the way how ARC clears memory.